# Why does "mene" appear twice in Daniel 5?

Tags: words, aramaic, riddle, daniel-book-of

In the famous phrase from Belshatzar's feast in Daniel 5, "mene mene tekal u'farsin", the word "mene" is explained by Daniel to refer to Hashem having numbered Belshatzar's days as king (מנא -  מנה) ([Daniel 5:26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.5.26?with=all&lang=bi)). Why, then, is "mene" written twice in the phrase? Wouldn't one "mene" suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Metzudat David](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Metzudat_David_on_Daniel.5.26.2?lang=bi) writes that the doubled phrase implies that G-d's calculation here is precise.

[R. Moshe Alshich](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chavatzelet_HaSharon_on_Daniel.5.26.4?lang=bi) writes that the first occurrence of the word (which is not interpreted explicitly by Daniel) means "You, Belshazzar, attempt to calculate the seventy years of Exile." The second occurrence then means "Correspondingly, G-d has numbered the remaining days of your kingdom."

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%95